# Build Signed APK failed - Can't find common super class of [android/content/Context]

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-context, onesignal

This is **Android** Project. Using **Normal Build** was successfull, but using signed Key i got this error :

```
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForFlavorRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [android/content/Context] (with 2 known super classes) and [com/onesignal/ADMMessageHandler] (with 1 known super classes)
```

Any Idea ?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you post here your proguard file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Proguard causes this problem.

Add this line to your Proguard file.

`-keep class com.onesignal.** { *; }`

And you should read this issue.
It may help you.
https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/154