# Proguard Issue while using htmlunit.jar library in android project

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, htmlunit, android-proguard

I have used the `htmlunit-2.15.jar` in my android project. When I am trying to create an signed apk it is throwing some proguard errors

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/activex/javascript/msxml/MSXMLScriptable] (with 2 known super classes) and [java/lang/Class] (with 2 known super classes)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:259)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/activex/javascript/msxml/MSXMLScriptable] (with 2 known super classes) and [java/lang/Class] (with 2 known super classes) at proguard.evaluation.value.TypedReferenceValue.findCommonClass(TypedReferenceValue.java:450)
```

So can you please help me in fixing this issue as my project is in live i need to immeadiately fix and relase the build. Issue in the progaurd when migrate from gradle **2.3.3** to **3.0.1** in android studio.

I have added these 2 lines in the proguard-rules.pro

```
-dontwarn com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.**
-keep class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.** { *; }

-dontwarn netscape.javascript.**
-keep class netscape.javascript.** { *; }
```

Comment: Did you checked this link ??



  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571266/build-signed-apk-failed-cant-find-common-super-class-of-android-content-cont

Comment: Yaah checked it didn't resolve my issue

Comment: Add this code in your dependency it worked for me.      configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
    }

Comment: Codelover can you make it some more clear

Comment: I think your error arises due to jar file.  add this code snippet in you dependency which is located in Build.gradle file of App.  
   configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
    }

Comment: My jar file doesn't contain anything related to com.android.support & support-v13

Comment: post your dependency

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/htmlunit-2.30.jar')
}

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlunit/files/htmlunit/2.15/htmlunit-2.15-bin.zip/download

In this zip file we will find the htmlunit-2.15.jar library

Comment: Codelover i did the changes it didn't help me

Answer (score 1):

Thanks i have sorted the solution and fixed it ,i just added the library

`implementation 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:2.5'`

in app build.gradle file

This library has all the missing classes in that htmlunit.jar.
And also added these 3 lines in my **progaurd file.**

```
-keep class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomNode { *; }
-keep class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.SimpleScriptable { *; }
-keep class net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.** { *; }
```

**The above changes fixed my issue and now i am able to generate the signed apk file**